# How do you get past the Abykos in the Buried Crossroads without combat?

Tags: torment-tides-of-numenera

Every encounter in Torment:Tides of Numenera has a solution that doesn't require combat.

I focused the mirrors on the creatures to reveal the Abykos. They want something to eat.

I have only 3 dialogue options at this point:

"Stay back. I have no food for you here."

"I don't want to hurt you. Return to your realm."

"Leave this place or die."

If I don't give them something to eat, they attack and I have to kill them. As I don't have anything to offer them, I can't avoid combat.

What can I offer them to avoid combat?

Comment: Sometimes that solution is "don't do the action that leads to combat" though.

Comment: But that's metagaming - doing something based on knowledge that you find out later. A pacifist scientist would want to find out what would happen.

Comment: Are you far in the game now? Because with that attitude I seriously doubt that "Every encounter has a solution that doesn't require combat". Same was true for original Torment - only about 3 (?) fights were mandatory, but if you were a good guy who liked snooping into stuff you ended up fighting quite a lot more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abykos feed on transdimensional energy. As far as I know, there is no way to avoid this fight apart from not looking into the central mirror.

Speculation here: Callistege is a transdimensional being, possibly, you could offer her as food. Though I doubt she likes that, even if it is possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can feed them [The Foreman's Children](https://numenera.gamepedia.com/The_Foreman%27s_Children).